# Summarizing count and value totals from a column of dataframe based on conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, summary

I have a dataframe with (say) invoice wise price adjustment values for different products.

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A','A','B','B','C','C','A','A','A','A'],
              'sum'  : [10,-10,10,10,0,-10,-10,0,10,0]})
```

I need to create a summary table such as under for col1 = 'A':

```
           Count    Value
Positve
Negative
NIL
```

As of now, I am doing this as under:

```
result = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Count','Value'],index=['Positve','Negative','NIL'])
result.iloc[0,0] = df[(df['col1'] = 'A') & (df['sum'] > 0)]['sum'].count()
result.iloc[0,1] = df[(df['col1'] = 'A') & (df['sum'] > 0)]['sum'].sum()
result.iloc[1,0] = df[(df['col1'] = 'A') & (df['sum'] < 0)]['sum'].count()
result.iloc[1,1] = df[(df['col1'] = 'A') & (df['sum'] < 0)]['sum'].sum()
result.iloc[2,0] = df[(df['col1'] = 'A') & (df['sum'] == 0)]['sum'].count()
result.iloc[2,1] = df[(df['col1'] = 'A') & (df['sum'] == 0)]['sum'].sum()
```

Is there a better and faster way to do this instead of writing a line of code for each value in the summary table? I couldn't think of anything here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use [`np.sign`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html) with mapping [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to new column, then filter only `A` and aggregate `count` with `sum` in [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) by named aggregations:

```
df['new'] = np.sign(df['sum']).map({0:'NIL', 1:'POS', -1:'NEG'})

df1 = df[df['col1'].eq('A')].groupby('new').agg(Count=('new','size'), Val=('sum','sum'))
print (df1)
     Count  Val
new            
NEG      2  -20
NIL      2    0
POS      2   20
```

If need count all values add another column to `groupby`:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['col1', 'new']).agg(Count=('new','size'), Val=('sum','sum'))
print (df2)
          Count  Val
col1 new            
A    NEG      2  -20
     NIL      2    0
     POS      2   20
B    POS      2   20
C    NEG      1  -10
     NIL      1    0
```

Comment: For others, just to clarify on the syntax about agg(), the first '' is the column name from the dataframe and the next '' is the function for aggregation.